# jChartFX - How to show Tool Bar

Tags: jquery, jchartfx

Hi I just use jChartFx to present charts and graphs in my website. At some point, I want to show the Tool Bar within the Charts to change the motif or the palette. How should I do this in jQuery ? I just search in their documentation on how to do it but only in C# (Refer [this](http://support.softwarefx.com/Chart_FX_8/article/2501002#!2502258))

Is this possible ? Thank you.